# Is Sieve of Eratosthenes using bitset faster than the one using bool array?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++14

I have written the Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm to find all the primes `<=10^8` using bitset and bool array(separately) for a [problem](https://www.spoj.com/problems/TDPRIMES/). In the problem, I'm simply asked to print the prime numbers according the given sequence of positions(1,101,201,301... till `<=10^8`).

Here is my code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define N 100000001
//bool pFlag[N];
bitset<N> pFlag;
void sieve() {
    for(int i=4; i<N; i+=2) {
        pFlag[i] = 1;
    }
    cout << 2 << "\n";
    int pCount = 0;
    for(int i=3; i<N; i+=2) {
        if(!pFlag[i]) {
            pCount++;
            if(pCount == 100) {
                cout << i << "\n";
                pCount = 0;
            }
            if((long long int)i*i<N) {
                for(int j=i*i; j<N; j+=i) {
                    pFlag[j] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
int main() {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    sieve();
}
```

The problem is, as per my understanding and according to this [blog](https://cp-algorithms.com/algebra/sieve-of-eratosthenes.html) the sieve algorithm using bitset/vector is supposed to be slower than the one using bool array.

> Such an approach, which is called bit-level compression, will
>   complicate the operations with these bits. Read or write operation on
>   any bit will require several arithmetic operations and ultimately slow
>   down the algorithm.

However, it seems not to be the case when I submit it in the online judge(SPOJ). Where I get a execution time of 0.99s for the code using bool array and 0.59s for the code using bitset.(I have used the exact same code, just changed the container)

Using bitset:
[image]

Using bool array:
[image]

Can someone please explain me if my understanding of bitset being slower than the bool array is wrong or there's something I'm missing?

**Extra information:**

The execution time in my laptop is like this:

```
bitset              bool array
19.021366000s       5.579701000s
19.163211000s       5.099894000s
18.765502000s       4.332410000s
```

I also got similar results in the `repl.it` which supports my understanding, so I didn't add it here before.

Comment: Did you try and run both the codes multiple times? The timing may fluctuate depending on load on the server, though its only of a few ms

Comment: I wouldn't jump into conclusion from a specific example, of a specific code running one time on a specific architecture using specific compiler optimizations.

Comment: `#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;` - Please don't ever do that.

Comment: There are more factors in execution time than just counting operations. Bitsets pack stuff closer together, so it's more cache friendly.

Comment: Did you test an optimized build of your code or a unoptimized debug build (usually the default if you don't tell the compiler to do otherwise).

Comment: @amit That might be the probable reason since in my machine I get the results that support my understanding. In that case, how do I know which code will run faster beforehand ?

Comment: @JesperJuhl I ran the exact same code that I posted here.

Comment: @Abhishek I did. I got the same result every time.

Comment: @ChasedByDeath *Can someone please explain me if my understanding of bitset being slower than the bool array is wrong or there's something I'm missing?* -- Don't time code based on what the man behind some curtain is doing (the online judge).  Run the code locally and set the proper compiler switches, or go to a benchmarking website such as [this one](http://quick-bench.com/).

Comment: @JesperJuhl is talking about compiler flags, which are passed on the command line and are not part of the code.  You didn't show those.

Comment: @MarkRansom Sorry for my lack of knowledge. I am using codeblocks ide which uses gcc version 5.1.0 and as compiler flags I have -std=c++14 marked. That's all I know of.

Comment: Note: with `N == 100000001`, not an OF issue, yet with `N` near `INT_MAX`, `j+=i` in `for(int j=i*i; j<N; j+=i) {` is prone to overflow even if `j=i*i` does not.

Comment: You're not compiling with optimizations enabled. Benchmarking unoptimized code is pretty pointless, since the compiler isn't targeting fast execution. On GCC use `-O3` to enable maximum optimization.

Comment: @BessieTheCow I've checked adding `#pragma GCC Optimize("O3")` in the code. There's not much changes in the execution times that I get in my machine. Also it gives same result in the OJ as before which are contradictory as I mentioned in the post.

Comment: The bitset version is faster on my machine too. Like I said before it could be caused by bitsets being more cache friendly.